# Leanft Custom Framework HTML reports are not generated

Tags: java, selenium, report, leanft

Below is my SAMPLE code in which i am trying to create a simple report using the Leanft in which i am getting on result xml file.

```
@Test
public void Google() throws Exception {
 Reporter.init();
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.google.com");
    Thread.sleep(4000);
   if( driver.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase("google")){
       Reporter.reportEvent("test", "test",Status.Failed);
   }
Reporter.generateReport();
driver.quit();
}
```

Comment: Please help me out here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As specified in the docs](https://leanft-help.saas.hpe.com/en/14.01/HelpCenter/Content/HowTo/CustomFrameworks.htm), if you're going to use a custom framework you'll also need to initialize the SDK (`SDK.init()` and `SDK.cleanup()`)

E.G.

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    // initialize the SDK and report only once per process
    try{
        ModifiableSDKConfiguration config = new ModifiableSDKConfiguration();
        config.setServerAddress(new URI("ws://myServerAddress:5095"));
        SDK.init(config);
        Reporter.init();

        //put your test code here.

        //Generate the report and cleanup the SDK usage.
        Reporter.generateReport();
        SDK.cleanup();
    }  catch(Exception e){
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing wrong with your code as the report generates as you told it too.

However, I believe you were wanting something more like this to show that it PASSES when it finds the Google title:

```
@Test
public void Google() throws Exception {
    Reporter.init();
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.google.com");
    Thread.sleep(4000);
    if( driver.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase("google")){
        Reporter.reportEvent("test", "test",Status.Passed);
    } else {
        Reporter.reportEvent("test","test",Status.Failed);
    }
    Reporter.generateReport();
    driver.quit();
}
```